# Reverse id encoding for url

Tags: php, string, encoding

I'm looking for a function (php) to encode int id into string looks like result of md5, or uuid. 
Requirements for function is next:

- encoding must be reverse
- fast
- encoded string must be unique
- desired chars are [a-z0-9-]

Security is not the point, I just need use such id conversion "perceived" security by customers, indeed used other approaches to make link available only for order owner.

Workflow I see now: I take encoded string from URL, decode it to int, make query using this int value.

I thought about approach, when together with id need store some hash, and use this hash in urls, but if I can use function with requirements I'm asking for, it would be great, because I don't want to add separate filed, index by this field, etc.

Comment: Ah, security through obfuscation :) As long as you do not neglect the rest, should be fine though.

Answer (score 2):

Try base64_encode/base64_decode.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php

Comment: This is clean and simple. If you wanted to be "slightly more secure" you could add an number of simple manipulations to your string: add a number to the ASCII value (Caesar shift), XOR it with a bit pattern (do it again and it reverses...). These are not cryptographically strong, but someone who would say "hey that looks base64 encoded!" and tries to reverse it, still doesn't see the original string.